# First Ionic installation

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, installation, ionic-native

./src/index.tsx 1:44
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:44)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/My PC/Ionic_Project/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
> | $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
> |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this command
npm cache clean -f